# generate sequence of chars for input to Scanner

Tags: java

I'm puzzled by an exercise I am trying out from Bruce Eckels Thinking In Java 4E page 332.

The question asks create a class that produces a sequence of chars.  Adapt this class so that it can be an input to a Scanner object (i.e. implement Readable).

My question is that I wrote my code very similar to the example Bruce gives in his book.  But his example works, and mine does not.  What did I do wrong?

Note: this is not homework (it is personal study of the book only, not a classroom assignment).  Below is Bruce's code first, which works, then my answer to the exercise question based on his, which doesn't work.  Of course I see that there is a buffer overflow exception but I don't see why that happens for me and not Bruce (the buffer seems to be provided by the Scanner class, since it's not declared anywhere ... but I'm getting lost at that point).

Bruce's code (WORKS):

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;

//based on example in Bruce Eckels Thinking in Java 4th edition
//see page 332: "adapting to an interface".

public class RandomWords implements Readable {

  //random number generator
  private static Random rand = new Random(47);

  //an array of lowercase letters
  private static final char[] lowers =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

  //number of words to generate
  private int count;

  //constructor
  public RandomWords(int count) { this.count = count; }

  //read method (required to implement Readable)
  public int read(CharBuffer cb) {

    if(count-- == 0)
      return -1; // Indicate end of input

    //ten letter random word
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      cb.append(lowers[rand.nextInt(lowers.length)]);
    }
    cb.append(" "); //separate tokens with a space ?
    return 10; // Number of characters appended
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new RandomWords(8));
    while(s.hasNext())
      System.out.println(s.next());
  }

}
```

now here is my code (DOESN'T WORK)

```
import java.nio.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RandomWord implements Readable {

    //length of random word to be generated
    private int count;

    //Random number generator
    private static Random rand = new Random(47);

    //Array of letters to choose from
    private  static final char[] letters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    //Constructor
    RandomWord(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    //read method (required to implement Readable)
    public int read(CharBuffer cb){

        //no input
        if(count == 0)
          return -1;

        //generate letters
        for(int i = 0; i < count; ++count)
            cb.append(letters[rand.nextInt(letters.length)]);

        //separate tokens with a space ?
        cb.append(" ");

        //return number of letters generated
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new RandomWord(8));
            System.out.println(s.next());
            //also no joy:
            //if (s.hasNext())
            //  System.out.println(s.next());
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:513)
    at java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.put(HeapCharBuffer.java:163)
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.append(CharBuffer.java:1375)
    at RandomWord.read(RandomWord.java:30)
    at java.util.Scanner.readInput(Scanner.java:849)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1414)
    at RandomWord.main(RandomWord.java:41)


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this loop not end ...

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; ++count)
```

change in

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

Comment: So simple!  Thank you - that does it.